# Checking query results against exploded array - Wordpress, php

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I have some brands listed against a user in the db which are input as a comma seperated list in the users profile - i get the individual brands associated to the user back by as follows 
`$brand_name = get_user_meta($user_id, 'brand', true);
$brands = explode(', ', $brand_name);`

it works ok.

I am now creating brand pages which list their products, this is easy but i want to prevent users seeing the pages of the brands that they arent subscribed to.

my code that isnt working is below:

```
    foreach ( $results as $result ){
        $brand_name = get_user_meta($user_id, 'brand', true);
        $brands = explode(', ', $brand_name);
        if($brands = $result->brand) {
        echo '<h2>Title: ' . $result->title . '</h2><br/>';
    } else {
            echo 'You can\'t view that brand';
        }
    }
```

I think i need to do some sort of nested foreach/for loop but not sure - Thanks in advance.

Comment: `if($brands = $result->brand)` - even if `=` wasn’t the _assigment_ operator, it would still not make much sense to try and compare a string value with an array. // http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: @CBroe how stupid of me! thanks - all i needed was `in_array()` thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ( $results as $result )
        {
            $brand_name = get_user_meta($user_id, 'brand', true);
            $brands = explode(', ', $brand_name);
            if(in_array($result->brand,$brands)) 
            {
                echo '<h2>Title: ' . $result->title . '</h2><br/>';
            } 
            else
            {
                echo 'You can\'t view that brand';
            }
        }
```

use in_array()